# Python regex fractions

Tags: python, regex

I'm trying to use regex to replace instances of a fraction (specifically 1/2) with the decimal equivalent

```
string = "7 1/2"
re.sub(r'[1/2]', '.5', string)
```

Firstly, I think the above replaces all instances of 1, /, 2 with .5, whereas I'm trying to find and replace the entire term "1/2"

Secondly, how do you handle the leading space before the fraction itself?

Comment: "I think the above..." Have you tried or is this just speculation?

Comment: instead of `[ ]` use `()` to capture the fraction group

Comment: well when I try it on 7 1/2 I get 7 .5.5.5 so I believe its true in that case, just not sure if thats the generalized outcome

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A general solution should be like below which should use a lambda function in the replacement part of `re.sub`.

```
>>> import re
>>> from __future__ import division
>>> s = "7 1/2"
>>> re.sub(r'(\d+)/(\d+)', lambda m: str(int(m.group(1))/int(m.group(2))), s)
'7 0.5'
>>> re.sub(r'(\d+)/(\d+)', lambda m: str(int(m.group(1))/int(m.group(2))), '7 9/2')
'7 4.5'
```

Update:

```
>>> re.sub(r'^(\d+)\s+(\d+)/(\d+)$', lambda m: str(float(int(m.group(1)) + int(m.group(2))/int(m.group(3)))), '7 9/2')
'11.5'
```

Comment: Thanks, how would you add the converted fraction part back to the integer though? "7 1/2" should be "7.5" and "7 9/2" should be "11.5"

Answer (score 2):

As an alternative to regex, if you *always* have a single number per string, and the fractional part is separated from the whole number part by whitespace, you could use the [`fractions`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/fractions.html#module-fractions) module to perform a conversion:

```
from fractions import Fraction

for s in '7 1/2', '1 33/66', '22 21/22', '123', '123.45':
    f = sum(Fraction(x) for x in s.split())
    print(float(f))
```

**Output**

```
7.5
1.5
22.9545454545
123.0
123.45
```